# How to convert BigDecimal to Decimal properly?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, bigdecimal

I am trying to convert a double value e.g. `12.55` to `BigDecimal` with this code:

```
BigDecimal unitPrice = new BigDecimal(product.getUnitPrice());
```

As a result, I got something like this `12.550000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125` then I have to rounded it off with this code:

`unitPrice.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`

and got a result like this `12.55` which is fine. However, when I'm going to set this as a parameter for inserting to MySQL database with this code:

`addProduct.setBigDecimal(4, unitPrice.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));`

So when I run it, I got this SQL Error:

`Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'price_per_unit' at row 2`

I know that the problem was in this code:

`addProduct.setBigDecimal(4, unitPrice.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));`

as I have debugged it at this line of code, the value was

`12.550000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125`

The column's data type in MySQL that I have set was `DECIMAL(3,2)`.

How come it is not working even when I rounded it off? I have tried searching for a solution and cannot find anything relevant. How do you really set the decimal properly? I assume that you know what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does `product.getUnitPrice()` return a floating-point value? This is the real problem.

Comment: @EJP It returns double actually.

Comment: [`double` *is* floating-point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) actually, and this is still the real problem. You shouldn't have to be rounding just to store into a database. Don't use floating-point for money.

Comment: @EJP Yeah you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Decimal (3,2)` means the number has a total of three digits, one to the left and two to the right. `12.55` does not fit into this.
Was you intention to store three to the left? It would be `decimal(5,2)`

Comment: Oh yeah.... You're right... How come I didn't realise that? Thank you so much Thomas. It was just a simple solution. lol :)

Answer (score 0):

of if you want to keep DECIMAL(3,2) the code would be

```
new BigDecimal(12.55f, new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)).setScale(2);
```